# SQL - Exclude item in list if item has already been used

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know there is a good way to do this but i cant think of any for some reason. I need to return a list of available promotional codes that the user has not already used. I was going to build a temp table of all the available promotional codes and then loop through to build the list but this seems like a horrible idea.  Here is my code so far:

```
DECLARE
@Email AS NVARCHAR(500) = ''
--AS
--BEGIN
    --Build Active Promotions
        SELECT
            Promotion_ID AS 'ID', 
            Promotional_Code, 
            [Description]
        INTO #ActivePromotions
        FROM [dbo].[WBG_Promotional_Code] 
        WHERE
            [Start_Date] < GETDATE() AND
            GETDATE() < [End_Date]

--Build Count
DECLARE @Count AS INT = (SELECT  COUNT(ID) FROM #ActivePromotions)
DECLARE @Tick INT = 0;

--Build List
WHILE @Count < @Tick BEGIN     

    SET @Tick = @Tick + 1;
END;


DROP TABLE #ActivePromotions
```

--END

Here is the purchase table:

```
Purchase_ID, 
Email, 
Product_Name, 
Purchase_Date, 
Purchase_Amount, 
Promotional_Code
```

Here is the Promotional Codes Table

```
Promotion_ID, 
Promotional_Code, 
Start_Date, 
End_Date, 
Description
```

The only thing I could think of at first was do a LEFT join to Purchasing on Promotional_Code to join the tables and try to filter further but could not get that to work. Open to ideas.

Comment: Always try to keep your query as short as possible via input/output samples. Paragraphing if can be avoided would help more.

Comment: LEFT JOIN and then WHERE IS NULL

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [SQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You might get better performance from a `NOT EXISTS` correlated sub-query than you will with a `LEFT JOIN`.

**Edit:** Expanded the query based on OP's comments & posted answer.

Assumption: A "used code" is a code from the purchase table that's associated with the parameterized `@Email` address.

```
WITH usedCodes AS
(
  SELECT 
    Email,
    Promotional_Code
  FROM
    dbo.WBG_Purchase
  WHERE
    Email = @Email
  GROUP BY
    Email,
    Promotional_Code
)
SELECT
    p.Promotion_ID AS 'ID', 
    p.Promotional_Code, 
    p.[Description]
INTO #ActivePromotions
FROM dbo.WBG_Promotional_Code as p
WHERE
    p.[Start_Date] < GETDATE() 
    AND
    GETDATE() < p.[End_Date]
    AND
    NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1 
       FROM usedCodes as uc
       WHERE p.Promotional_Code = uc.Promotional_Code);
```

The CTE limits the data set from the purchase table to the purchases tied to the email address you're sending into the procedure. The correlated subquery looks for codes in the promotion code table that don't appear in the CTE data set.

Comment: No did not work. It needs to filter on the email somewhere in the purchasing table.

Comment: Well I thought I had a working answer but I just tested it again and my solution is still not working and your is not working.

Comment: This might be closer to a working solution. See the edited query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest this answer. I have not tested it a lot yet but appears to be working.

```
    SELECT
    Promotion_ID AS 'ID', 
    Promotional_Code, 
    [Description]
FROM [dbo].[WBG_Promotional_Code] as c
WHERE
    [Start_Date] < GETDATE() AND
    GETDATE() < [End_Date] AND
    Promotional_Code NOT IN (SELECT [Promotional_Code] FROM [dbo].[WBG_Purchase] as p WHERE p.Promotional_Code IS NOT NULL AND p.Email = @Email)
```